# Have Selenium Do the same process for multiple URLS

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I created a script that goes to a property auction site that monitors the price and alerts me of any of the changes. I originally made it to monitor 1 url at a time. I now need it to monitor more then 1 url and do the same exact process at the same time.

I've tried looping the urls in browser.get but that doesn't seem to work for me(idk if i wrote it wrong, probably did). But i need it to either, open a tun of new tabs and go to the urls, or another way for it to monitor everything.

The Original Script for 1 property url, works perfectly, And the only difference between that and the code below is `browser.get`.

PS: If script is run, and auction urls are expired (meaning theres no price it can look at) there will be a error

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import ssl
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

urls = ['https://www.hubzu.com/property/90089436968-730-Trillium-Ln-Lilburn-GA-30047',
'https://www.hubzu.com/property/90016097522-225-Marriott-Ave-Schenectady-NY-12304',
'https://www.hubzu.com/property/90016098285-17-Spring-Meadows-Dr-Ormond-Beach-FL-32174'
]

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# Start URL switch tryouts.

while True:
    for url in urls:
        browser.get((url))


       #This is the process i need all urls to do.
        time.sleep(2)
        address = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').find('span', {'class':'h1'}).text
        propertyprice = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid')
        currentBidText = propertyprice.text
        try:                                
            WebDriverWait(browser, 90000).until_not(
                EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-bid'), currentBidText)
                )
        finally:
            print("+++ Send notifications.")
            account_sid = "***"
            auth_token = "***"
            client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

            PhoneNumber1 = "+***"
            PhoneNumber2 = "+***"
            print("+ Send notifications to: ", PhoneNumber1, " and ", PhoneNumber2)

            sendTo1 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber1 + "\"}"
            print("+ sendTo1: ", sendTo1)
            sendTo2 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber2 + "\"}"
            print("+ sendTo2: ", sendTo2)

            notify_service_sid = "***"
            notification = client.notify.services(notify_service_sid).notifications.create(
                    body='There has been a change at: '+address,
                    to_binding=[sendTo1, sendTo2]
                )

            print("+ Notification SID: ", notification.sid)

            print("+++ Exit.")
    continue
```

Comment: So your question is how to open multiple tabs and cycle through them?

Comment: As long as it monitors the price as it cycles through then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be mostly fine and cycles through them for me. Unfortunately all the properties are not for sale, so they all give me errors and I cannot produce the expected behaviour. I think you should implement a `try:` and `except:`, the `finally:` runs regardless of what happened, and I wouldn't imagine you want an update every 2 seconds XD. You also don't need `continue` at the end, it does nothing. The code

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import ssl
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

urls = ['https://www.hubzu.com/property/90089436968-730-Trillium-Ln-Lilburn-GA-30047',
        'https://www.hubzu.com/property/90016097522-225-Marriott-Ave-Schenectady-NY-12304',
        'https://www.hubzu.com/property/90016098285-17-Spring-Meadows-Dr-Ormond-Beach-FL-32174']

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# Start URL switch tryouts.

while True:
    for url in urls:
        browser.get(url)

        # This is the process i need all urls to do.
        time.sleep(2)
        address = soup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser').find('span', {'class': 'h1'}).text
        try:
            propertyprice = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('span.current-bid')
            currentBidText = propertyprice.text
            WebDriverWait(browser, 90000).until(
                EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.current-bid'), currentBidText)
                )
        except Exception as e:
            print("an error occurred on property {}:\n{}".format(address.strip(), e))
        finally:
            pass
            # print("+++ Send notifications.")
            # account_sid = "***"
            # auth_token = "***"
            # client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
            #
            # PhoneNumber1 = "+***"
            # PhoneNumber2 = "+***"
            # print("+ Send notifications to: ", PhoneNumber1, " and ", PhoneNumber2)
            #
            # sendTo1 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber1 + "\"}"
            # print("+ sendTo1: ", sendTo1)
            # sendTo2 = "{\"binding_type\":\"sms\",\"address\":\"" + PhoneNumber2 + "\"}"
            # print("+ sendTo2: ", sendTo2)
            #
            # notify_service_sid = "***"
            # notification = client.notify.services(notify_service_sid).notifications.create(
            #         body='There has been a change at: '+address,
            #         to_binding=[sendTo1, sendTo2]
            #     )
            #
            # print("+ Notification SID: ", notification.sid)
            #
            # print("+++ Exit.")
```

Does cycle through all the properties, and a sample output for me is:

```
an error occurred on property 730
Trillium Ln

 Lilburn, GA 30047:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.current-bid"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

an error occurred on property 225 Marriott Ave

 Schenectady, NY 12304:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.current-bid"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

an error occurred on property 17 Spring Meadows Dr

 Ormond Beach, FL 32174:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.current-bid"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

an error occurred on property 730
Trillium Ln

 Lilburn, GA 30047:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.current-bid"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

an error occurred on property 225 Marriott Ave

 Schenectady, NY 12304:
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.current-bid"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565498 (ea082db3280dd6843ebfb08a625e3eb905c4f5ab),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

and so on in an infinite loop...

Comment: Yeah, its cycling the issue i'm having now is everytime it cycles to the next url it alerts me even tho theres no change. What i think is happening is it sees the first price for the first url so when it switches it alerts me because of the new price on the new url

Comment: @reggiejones That's what I was trying to explain. EVERYTHING in the `finally:` block will run EVERY iteration. To quote myself "I wouldn't imagine you want an update every 2 seconds" I would recommend at least protecting your messaging code inside `if`. Perhaps `if property_bid != old_property_bid:` or something like that. The problem with that would be when there is an exception, there is no bid to compare it to. However, that is a separate problem and it sounds like this post has solved your problem of cycling through URLs. If so, you can click the check mark by my post and close the thread.

Comment: @reggiejones You could do something like `for index in range(len(urls)-1, -1, -1):`; `browser.get(urls[index])`; and then during an exception `#code to message yourself there was an error`;`del urls[index]`

Comment: @reggiejones There are many solutions though, I'm sure you will think of something